# Add access points automaticali to linux debian

Tags: bash, scripting, wifi

I have to add multiple AP and passwords to multiple Linux machines and need to automate that. Recently I've write a bash script to write configs to files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` like the files that were generated by the system. But without success.

EXAMPLE:

I have a file `AP.txt` with MAC addresses, SSID and password:

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x1;ssid1;pass1
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2;ssid2;pass2
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x3;ssid3;pass3
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x4;ssid4;pass4
```

and multiple machines:

```
pc1
pc2
pc3
...
```

I would like to make a script to add those AP to my computers automaticaly, so that every machine can connect automatically to the nearest AP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have root ssh keys setup and locally generated templates, stat with this;

```
for HOST in $HOSTS ; do
    scp wifi-templates/* $HOST:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
    ssh $HOST 'U=$(ls -1 /home/ | head -n 1); perl -pi -e "s/(permissions=user:)you(:;)/$1'$U'$2/g" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*'
done
```

Templates;

```
while read L ; do
    SSID=$(echo $L | cut -d ";" -f 1)
       N=$(echo $L | cut -d ";" -f 2)
    PASS=$(echo $L | cut -d ";" -f 3)
    cp template $N
    perl -pe 's/SSID/'$SSID'/g;s/PASS/'$PASS'/g' $N
done < AP.txt
```

*This code is for demonstration only (untested and may require tweaking for it to work) Please read the man page of each command before use;

- [bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)
- [scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)
- [head](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head)
- [ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)
- [ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)
- [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)
- [perl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perl)
- [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)
- [cp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need to do the template, need help with that. I tried to manualy insert a template to /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ but when near an AP that I added it doesnt connect to them.